# Implement Function Zero-One

Tags: python, label

Suppose a list of labels `label_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]` (`0` is class 0, `1` is class 1 and `2` is class 2) and `X` a list of lists (i.e. the features). Each list of `X` has a unique label from `label_list` associated.

[image]

How can I implement a function `lambda` in python to create the Function Zero-One?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what `X` might look like :

```
X = [[0.4, 0.2, 0.232], [0.3434, 0.243985, 0.9834], [0.3434, 0.345, 0.198459], [0.34324, 0.909834, 0.93849], [0.983498, 0.9384938, 0.983489], [0.768759, 0.9384, 0.897629], [0.14739, 0.872847, 0.62874], [0.6874, 0.87387, 0.83787], [0.8723874, 0.873764, 0.7527648], [0.762, 0.2648, 0.768738]]
```

Be aware that C is the associated class, i is the number of the class (i.e. either 0, 1 or 2) and t is the t-th vector/list of `X`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what x looks like, and what you'd want the functions output to look like?

Comment: What are the variables `t` and `i`?

Comment: What is C? What represents `t` and `i`?

Comment: I am really sorry! I will modify the question.

Comment: can you also add the example output for the X list you provided?